# Getting images to align side-by-side and making DIV with image not move with text?

Tags: html, css

This is my working code for a HTML auto dealer template which does the job, but esthetically, isn't quite that pleasing and is very functional
(use Expand snippet on all of these to see the design properly):

```css
body {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.3;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.004);
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
}

body {
font-family: Fabriga, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
background-color: #F5FFFA;
}

@font-face {
font-family: Fabriga;
 src:url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Regular.eot?v=1.1.0");
 src:url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Regular.eot?#iefix&v=1.1.0") format("embedded-opentype"),
 url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Regular.woff2?v=1.1.0") format("woff2"),
 url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Regular.woff?v=1.1.0") format("woff"),
 url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Regular.ttf?v=1.1.0") format("truetype"),
 url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Regular.svg?v=1.1.0#Regular") format("svg");
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal
}

@font-face {
font-family: FabrigaMed;
src:url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Medium.eot?v=1.1.0");
 src:url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Medium.eot?#iefix&v=1.1.0") format("embedded-opentype"),
 url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Medium.woff2?v=1.1.0") format("woff2"),
 url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Medium.woff?v=1.1.0") format("woff"),
 url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Medium.ttf?v=1.1.0") format("truetype"),
 url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Medium.svg?v=1.1.0#Medium") format("svg");
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal
}

header {
background-color: #C71585;
margin-bottom: 3px;
border-radius: 4px 6px;
padding: 20px;
}

header {
margin-left: 20px;
}

header h1, header h2, header h3 {
color: #FFFFFF;
}

div.feld-name-title h2 {
color: red;
}


div.usecc1 {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin-bottom: 30px;
border: 3px solid;
border-radius: 6px 6px;
font-size: 18px;
display: table;
margin-left: 40px;
}
div.usecc1-header {
width: 1000px;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-right: 40px;
}

div.usecc1-header .price {
font-size: 18px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

ul.daldry {
margin-left: 40px;
}
ul.daldry > li {
margin-left: 40px;
font-size: 18px;
display: table-cell;
padding: 3px;
}
ul.daldry > li::after {
content: ' | ';
}

.usecc1-img {
float: left;
padding: 20px;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-right: 10px;
}
.usecc1-img img {
width: 420px;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
color: #333;
}

.feld-name-vehicle-additional-info {
   font-size: 14px;
   display: flex;
   margin-left: 200px;
   margin-right: 200px;
   margin-bottom: 22px;
   white-space: pre-line;
   padding: 5px;
   line-height: 18px;
}

.feld-name-title {
text-align: left;
color: #294c30;
}

.price {
font-family: FabrigaMed, sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
float: right;
margin-top: -60px;
margin-right: 100px;
}

.feld-name-title h3 {
    font-family: FabrigaMed, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.375rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: normal;
}


.specs-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
<H1>SOUTHSIDE MOTORS</H1>
<h3>10061 Southside Road, Newport, Southside, LOS ANGELES</h3>
<h3>555 121-234</h3>
</header>
<div class="content">
<p>We are based in Southside, Los Angeles.</p>
Content

<div class="usecc1">
<div class="usecc-header">
<div class="feld-name-title">
<h3>Buick Regal 2.0T Premium II</h3>
</div>
</div>
<div class="price">
<h3>$24,000</h3>
</div>
<ul class="daldry">
<li>2018</li>
<li>Hatchback</li>
<li>2.0L</li>
<li>10,000 miles</li>
<li>Automatic</li>
<li>Petrol</li>
</ul>

<div class="usecc1-img">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b4/2018_Buick_Regal_Sportback_Preferred_II_FWD%2C_Ebony_Twilight_Metallic%2C_front_right.jpg/500px-2018_Buick_Regal_Sportback_Preferred_II_FWD%2C_Ebony_Twilight_Metallic%2C_front_right.jpg">
</div>
<div class="feld-name-vehicle-additional-info">Ash black, ONLY 10,000 MILES!
</div>
</div>


<div class="usecc1">
<div class="usecc-header">
<div class="feld-name-title">
<h3>Subaru Leone 1.8 GL</h3>
</div>
</div>
<div class="price">
<h3>$5,999</h3>
</div>
<ul class="daldry">
<li>1994</li>
<li>Stationwagon</li>
<li>1.8L</li>
<li>70,000 miles</li>
<li>Automatic</li>
<li>Petrol</li>
</ul>

<div class="usecc1-img">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b5/1994_Subaru_L_Series_Deluxe_Sportswagon_station_wagon_%282011-10-23%29_01.jpg/1280px-1994_Subaru_L_Series_Deluxe_Sportswagon_station_wagon_%282011-10-23%29_01.jpg">
</div>
<div class="feld-name-vehicle-additional-info">white
</div>
</div>


</div>
```

I'm aiming for my design to look a bit like this: [design](https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?sort=distance&postcode=HA80AG&radius=1500&make=FORD&model=FIESTA&include-delivery-option=on) with the images stacked at the side and box with shadow on hover, but unlike the linked page, people can save the image.

I added in the rounded corners and border to show the DIVs here.

I also am trying to get the DIVs to be the same sort of size.

What I am looking for is advice on how to emulate the linked-to website's style in some ways (although there is no need for a sidebar) while making it user-friendly.